# How do I find the x-coordinates where the curve √(2x-1) is perpendicular to the line 3x + y =16?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, curves

I'm lost as to what I should do here. I got the derivative of the curve which I think is (2x-1)^-1/2. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You need to find the place where one of the derivatives is the negative reciprocal of the other.

Comment: Do you know how to take the derivative of the first function/ Find it and then set it equal to -1/3 and solve for x.

Answer (score 0):

Take the derivative of the first function and set it equal to 1/3 (the negative reciprocal of the derivative of the line) and solve. if you are not able to do this yourself you can punch it into online wolfram-alpha software.

Comment: Should be $1/3$ the line is $3x + y = 16$ which has slope $-3$

Comment: Just as a sanity check, that derivative will never be equal to $-1/3$ in the reals